# Laravel Horizon - Clearing Jobs From Queues - Call redis.replicate_commands()

Tags: laravel-horizon

- Horizon Version: 5.7
- Laravel Version: 8.40
- PHP Version: 7.4.22
- Redis Driver & Version: predis/phpredis 3.2.12 & predis 1.1
- Database Driver & Version:

Description:

```
ERR Error running script (call to f_281c23c60c642d42fdedcc1acc8adc7317dd75a5): @user_script:18: @user_script: 18: Write commands not allowed after non deterministic commands. Call redis.replicate_commands() at the start of your script in order to switch to single commands replication mode.
```

[Replicating commands instead of scripts](https://redis.io/commands/EVAL#replicating-commands-instead-of-scripts)

Howto call redis.replicate_commands() ?

Steps To Reproduce:

```
php artisan horizon:clear --queue=supplier_feeds_queue
```

Workaround:

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern *supplier_feeds_queue* | xargs redis-cli del
```